# ¿Es necesario incluir "break" en el "default" de la estructura de control "switch"?

Tags: java

Hace un tiempo que tengo esta duda y no encuentro info al respecto.

Dado el siguiente switch:

```
switch (valor) {
  case 1:
       //código..
       break;
  case 2:
       //código..
       break;
  case 3:
       //código..
       break;
  default:
       //código..
       break;
}
```

> Pregunta: ¿para qué está el **break** del **default**? ¿No es redundante? ¿No se supone
>   que si entró ahí es que ya se evaluaron todos los casos? ¿Para qué
>   decirle que corte si ya no hay mas casos a evaluar?

Veo por todos lados que incluyen el **break** en el **default**, y eso me lleva a pensar que no estoy comprendiendo del todo esta estructura de control

Comment: Sin saber exactamente el porqué, creo que se deba más a una formalidad. Yo estoy como tú, creo que sería lo mismo el ponerlo y no ponerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

`break` no es obligatorio en el `default` porque esta condición se cumpliría cuando ninguna de las otras se cumple y el código retornaría de modo natural. Sin embargo, la documentación aconseja ponerlo y las buenas prácticas de la comunidad de programadores (no sólo en Java sino también en otros lenguajes) también. Por eso todos los tutoriales respetables (empezando por los de la documentación oficial) ponen siempre `break` en todos los `case`.

Esto es lo que dice [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) al respecto:

> Technically, the final `break` is not required because flow falls out
>   of the `switch` statement. Using a `break` is recommended so that
>   modifying the code is easier and less error prone. The default section
>   handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the
>   `case` sections.
>
> ---
>
> Técnicamente, el `break` final no es necesario porque el flujo sale de
>   la declaración `switch`, pero se recomienda usarlo, para que el código
>   sea más fácil de actualizar (modificar)  y menos propenso a errores.
>   La sección `default` maneja todos los valores que una de las secciones
>   de casos no maneja explícitamente.

---

Tu duda fue planteada en [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/201777) y la respuesta aceptada indicando que conviene **usar `break` siempre** aduce tres motivos que me parecen totalmente válidos:

Sin embargo, todavía terminaría cada `case`, incluida la última, con una declaración `break`, por tres razones:

1. Refactorización. Si todos tus `case` terminan con `break`, puedes reordenarlos sin cambiar el significado. Esto hace que sea menos probable que tal reordenamiento introduzca una regresión.
2. Consistencia y menos sorpresa. La consistencia dice que tus `case` deben terminar consistentemente, a menos que en realidad tengan un significado diferente. El Principio de Menos Sorpresa (Principle of Least Surprise) dicta que las cosas similares deberían verse similares. Terminar la última rama de un bloque `switch` exactamente como los anteriores cumple con ambos, lo que facilita la lectura y la comprensión. Si dejas de lado el `break` explícito, la última rama será ópticamente diferente (lo cual es especialmente importante para el escaneo rápido), y para ver que realmente no es diferente, el lector tiene que descender al nivel esencial de lectura individual de declaraciones.
3. Protegiéndote a ti mismo. Si tienes la costumbre de terminar todas las ramas `switch`  con un `break`, se volverá automático después de un tiempo, y será menos probable que lo olvides accidentalmente donde importa. Acostumbrarte a poner el `break` al final de cada rama también ayuda a detectar las declaraciones `break` que faltan, lo cual es excelente para la depuración y la resolución de problemas.

Comment: Recordar que los `break`s se usan dentro de los condicionales `switch` tradicionales (los heredados de c/c++) por la naturaleza fallthruogh (algo como caer a través), ya que con estos rompemos el flujo. Pero hay ocasiones en los que es necesario no romper el flujo, por tanto no podemos generalizar diciendo que siempre es recomendable poner un `break` detrás de cada `case`. Además decir que desde Java 13 (en condición de preview) tenemos nuevos tipos de switches que no requieren break puesto que no son fallthruogh.

Answer (score 4):

Las sentencias break al igual que la sentencia default son opcionales. Se utilizan con el propósito de separar las alternativas. En el caso que indicas si no pones mas opciones a continuación del default puedes dejarlo sin el break (comprobando antes de que no te de problemas). Se ejecutaría el código de la misma manera, en cambio si indicas por ejemplo:

```
switch(condicion) {
case 1:
codigo
case 2:
codigo 
break;
}
```

Si en caso de que la condición sea 1, también se ejecutara la 2, puedes jugar con eso y hacer cosas interesantes pero lo dicho, break y default son opcionales y si default es el ultimo y ves que no dará problema no indicarle puedes hacerlo sin problemas. Si puedo aconsejarte te diría que lo indiques siempre, **por seguridad, para que sea refactorizable y tenga consistencia**. Vamos a poner que vuelves y añades algo mas y no te das cuenta que falta el break, por algo tan sencillo te puede hacer pasar un mal rato y te sera mas sencillo para debuggear.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente que tanto `break` como `default` son opcionales, pero no logro entender por qué el `break` en el `default`, ya que el `break` es para que no continué evaluando y el `default` es para cuando no encontró ningún caso, entonces si no encontró ningún caso ¿que otro caso va a seguir evaluando? Se entiende? De todas formas agradezco la respuesta

Comment: Al final se pone en caso de que en un futuro añadas mas casos, el default no tiene porque ir el ultimo, ningún caso tiene obligación de llevar el break si quieres, es una forma de separar el uno del otro.